# WebRequest timing out accessing a dropbox file. Browser can download the link fine

Tags: .net, vb.net, httpwebrequest

I've spent the day trying to work this one out. Please help!

I have a dropbox file shared link, its only the SQL Server express setup so no worries about sharing the live link.

My browser can download it just fine ... the file starts downloading in Chrome.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7dtg1d2cq9byccm/en_sql_server_2008_r2_express_edition_with_advanced_services_with_service_pack_2_x64_914054.exe.download?dl=1

However, then i attempt to download this file using a standard webrequest, the connection will time out each time.

Please note, the browser can download the file WITHOUT me being logged into my own dropbox, so i know its not permissions.

WebClient.DownloadFile also seems to fail, so i'm wondering if there is anything wrong with the address?

I've tried validating the cert using 'ServerCertificateValidationCallback' (But it doesn't call) and i've also setting the security protocol

Code is below:

```
Dim oReq As HttpWebRequest
oReq = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.dropbox.com/s/7dtg1d2cq9byccm/en_sql_server_2008_r2_express_edition_with_advanced_services_with_service_pack_2_x64_914054.exe.download?dl=1")
oReq.Timeout = 20000 '20 secs
oReq.Proxy = Nothing 'Specifically setting proxy to null can speed up the request (Src: StackOverflow)

''Setup credentials to avoid 401 error
oReq.UseDefaultCredentials = True
''oReq.PreAuthenticate = True
oReq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

'oReq.ContentType = "application/xml"

'oReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
'oReq.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10
'oReq.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en_US")

'oReq.Method = "GET"
'oReq.KeepAlive = True
'oReq.AllowAutoRedirect = True

'oReq.ReadWriteTimeout = 20000

Try
Using oResp As HttpWebResponse = oReq.GetResponse


End Using

Catch exWebTimeout As System.Net.WebException

End Try
```

I've left a lot of commenting so you guys can see what i've tried!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that this is because the file is over 1,000 MB, and your Timeout is set to 20 seconds. I believe the [Timeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx) will trigger if the request isn't complete within 20 seconds, and this file definitely won't be downloaded in that time. I would try downloading a much smaller file, one that you know can be downloaded within 20 seconds, and see if that works.